# How to run getter methods when adding objects to array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically I'm trying to implement a getter and a setter for my mutable array.
The getter gets called fine, however the setter is apparently only called when I directly set the array equal to something (using =). 
However the setter is not called when I add an item to the array using the code below:

```
[self.HighScores insertObject:newScore atIndex:i];
```

I see that there is a bunch of extra methods being "suggested" by xcode such as:

```
-(void) insertObject:(NSObject *)object inHighScoresAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

However having added it it still doesn't get called.'

Parts of my code are listed below:

HighScoreCollection.h:

```
@interface HighScoreCollection : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) NSMutableArray *HighScores;

- (bool) AddHighScore: (HighScore* )newScore;
- (NSMutableArray*) HighScores;
- (void) setHighScores:(NSMutableArray*)HighScores;
@end
```

HighScoreCollection.m:

```
@implementation HighScoreCollection

@synthesize HighScores = _HighScores;

- (void) setHighScores:(NSMutableArray*)HighScores
{
//setter code
}

- (NSMutableArray*) HighScores
{
//getter code
}

@end
```

How do I run a setter when I call array methods such as insert object etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a class
2. Inherit from `NSObject`
3. Inside the object from step 2 own a `NSMutableArray` in this custom object (composition design pattern [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)).

After that, call your custom setter in your new composite object when u want to.

Note: Your design is wrong, and you shouldn't thinks how the `NSMutableArray` insert object implement.

Comment: When you say "call your custom setter" do you mean I directly insert an object in the array?

Comment: No. My answer suggested u to wrap the NSMutableArray of Apple. As i said, It's not good. But, for your problem, it can help. U can expose your wanted methods and use them as u with. E.g U can alloc init the custom object and insert to the array in your way (call manually to your setter)